# Replace spaces with underscores via BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

Suppose i have a string, $str.
I want $str to be edited such that all the spaces in it are replaced by underscores.

Example

```
a="hello world"
```

I want the final output of

```
echo "$a"
```

to be **hello_world**

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
str="${str// /_}"
```

Answer (score 34):

```
$ a="hello world"
$ echo ${a// /_}
hello_world
```

According to bash(1):

> ```
> ${parameter/pattern/string}
> ```
>
> Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern
>   just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is  expanded  and the 
>   longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. 
>   If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern  are replaced
>   with  string.   Normally  only  the  first  match  is replaced.  If
>   pattern begins with #, it must match at the beginning of the
>   expanded value of parameter.  If pattern begins with %, it must match
>   at the end of the expanded value of  parameter. If string is null,
>   matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be
>   omitted.  If parameter is @ or *, the substitution  operation  is
>   applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.  If parameter  is an  array  variable  subscripted 
>   with  @ or *, the substitution operation is applied to each member of
>   the array  in  turn,  and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: Upping this for the reference to bash's documentation, missing in other answers.

Comment: what a genius solution

Answer (score 16):

Pure bash:

```
a="hello world"
echo "${a// /_}"
```

OR tr:

```
tr -s ' ' '_' <<< "$a"
```

Comment: +1 for just pure bash syntax!. Would like to know what's it doing behind scenes. Looks like it is doing 'sed' replacement operations. Any bash manual states for using such syntax?.

Comment: @user1587504: I believe `falsetru` has added relevant man section for this `Pattern substitution`

Answer (score 11):

With `sed` reading directly from a variable:

```
$ sed 's/ /_/g' <<< "$a"
hello_world
```

And to store the result you have to use the `var=$(command)` syntax:

```
a=$(sed 's/ /_/g' <<< "$a")
```

For completeness, with `awk` it can be done like this:

```
$ a="hello my name is"
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="_"} {for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf "%s%s",$i,OFS; printf "%s\n", $NF}' <<< "$a"
hello_my_name_is
```

Comment: Neither of these appears to deal with more than one space.

Comment: @WilliamHay you are right, didn't check with more than one space. Updated to use `sed .../g`, as default was doing it just once.

Comment: @fedorqui +1 for letting know usage of direct variable without echo piping to sed. I donot see direct help for this: '<<<' . Where is it defined in man pages. Could you please point me?

Comment: @user1587504 they are called "Here Strings". See http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html for more reference. They are useful.

Comment: @fedorqui . Thanks! for letting me know. I did used one with '<<' to check some EOF character when using isql inside a script. Usage of <<<  is nice. ..

Answer (score 10):

## Multiple spaces to one underscore

This can easily be achieved with a [**GNU shell parameter expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). In particular:

`${parameter/pattern/string}`

> If pattern begins with `/`, **all matches** of pattern are replaced with string.

with `+(pattern-list)`

> Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.

Hence:

```
$ a='hello world    example'

$ echo ${a// /_}
hello_world____example

$ echo ${a//+( )/_}
hello_world_example
```

However, [for this to work in a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/636222/39845) two amendments need to be made:

1. The parameter expansion requires encapsulation in double quotes `" "` to [prevent word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) with the [input field separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_Field_Separators) `$IFS`.
2. The `extglob` shell option needs to be enabled using the [`shopt` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html), for *extended* pattern matching operators to be recognised.

The bash script finally looks like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
a='hello world    example'
echo "${a//+( )/_}"
```

Comment: The aclaration for that to work in bash script is vital, thanks!