# Verify that Ansible's Collection dependencies are installed before play begins

Tags: ansible, ansible-collections

I use various Ansible Collections. When the Controller Node does not have them installed (e.g. because I installed `ansible-core` instead of `ansible`) then the play breaks halfway.

Is there a way to verify such dependencies before the play begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the command `ansible-galaxy` has no parameter to get clean output or to format it. So one need to do post-processing on the output.

```sh
 ansible-galaxy collection list 2>/dev/null | sed '0,/^-.*$/d;s/[ \t]*$//' | tr -s ' ' ','
```

To prevent using `loop` and in order to get all installed Ansible Collections for further processing, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Generate Collection Facts
    shell:
      cmd: >-
        echo "Collection,Version";
        ansible-galaxy collection list 2>/dev/null
        | sed '0,/^-.*$/d'
        | sed 's/[ \t]*$//'
        | tr -s ' ' ','
    register: collection_facts

  - name: Show Collection Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ collection_facts.stdout | community.general.from_csv(dialect='unix') }}"
```

will create a list of Comma Separated Values (CSV) for further processing.

To get a clean list output

- Drop Python warning messages according [Is it possible to remove error messages from Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20951181/6771046)
- Drop `ansible-galaxy` header from output according [Remove all lines before a match with `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365103/6771046)
- Remove trailing whitespaces from output according [How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line of some output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102021/266568)
- Replace whitespaces with comma according [Replace spaces ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19661345/6771046)

**Further Documentation**

- [Conversions - Parsing CSV files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_conversions.html#parsing-csv-files)
- [`community.general/plugins/filter /from_csv.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/filter/from_csv.py)

---

Regarding your comment

> *... it reports "what's installed". But if I want to know "what's missing" I need to perform more processing on that CSV output?*

Right, depending on what one try to achieve more tests can and/or need to be done. A quick example

```yaml
  - name: Register Collection Facts
    set_fact:
      collection_facts: "{{ collection_facts.stdout | community.general.from_csv(dialect='unix') }}"

  - name: Show Collection Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ collection_facts }}"

  - name: Show if 'community.general' is installed
    debug:
      msg: "Is installed"
    when: collection_facts | selectattr(search_key,'equalto',search_val) | list | count > 0
    vars:
      search_key: Collection
      search_val: community.general
```

**Thanks To**

- [Ansible check if key/value pair exists in list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957184/6771046)

---

**How to proceed further?**

There was a similar question in the past about [What Ansible command to list or verify installed modules — whether built-in or add-on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951759/) which has a good solution to [create a dictionary of installed collections and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75952396/6771046).

Comment: Thanks. This is very nice - it reports "what's installed". But if I want to know "what's missing" I need to perform more processing on that csv output?

Comment: Right, that's the case but would be very simple like. I am going to provide an example. ... just one moment.

Comment: Reading this again, it looks like a standalone play, just for verification. That is actually potentially quite useful. I can imagine putting all kinds of pre-flight tests / verifications in there.

Comment: Right, it is currently a standalone play just to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for learning purpose, for debugging to get familiar with the data structures. One need to adopt the approach for further use in his own case.

Comment: My answer below was what I needed... just a quick and effective fail-safe. But I'm marking your answer anyway because it's so comprehensive. Thanks for putting so much effort into it.

Answer (score 1):

I added a verification task at the beginning of the play:

```yaml
pre_tasks:
  - name: verify dependent collections are installed
    delegate_to: localhost
    ansible.builtin.shell: ansible-galaxy collection list | grep "{{item}}" | wc -l
    register: result
    failed_when: result.stdout != "1"
    changed_when: false
    loop:
      - community.general
      - amazon.aws
      - kubernetes.core
```